# Codeigniter database update issues

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am having issues in updating a table in my database (MySQL workbench).

The code in my model is the following:

```
function updateMail($new) {
    $data = array(
        'email' => $new
    );
    $this->db->where('email', $this->session->userdata('email'));
    $result = $this->db->update('person', $data);
    $error = $this->db->error();
    return $error;
}
```

My controller then places the return value in $result, and chechs `if(!isset($result))`.

> the problem is that sometimes the table updates, sometimes it doesn't,
>   but the error is always set.

The table basically contains persons with an id, name, firstname, password, username, email, and patient field.

Am I doing something wrong? Or is there a way a can display the error message it throws?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of error you have to check number of `affected row` in your query

```
function updateMail($new) {
    $data = array(
        'email' => $new
    );
    $this->db->where('email', $this->session->userdata('email'));
    $result = $this->db->update('person', $data);
    $afftectedRows = $this->db->affected_rows();
    if ($afftectedRows > 0) {
        return TRUE;
    } else {
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks mate, also i found out why it only worked occasionally... i search the entry on userdata email, but when i change it, i didn't change the userdata with it....